# Compiling a webapp against Tomcat 5.5 libraries and deploying on Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

I have a Struts2 webapp, in which I compiled using the Tomcat 5.5 libraries.

If I deploy this webapp on a Tomcat 6 server, should it still work without a hitch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, yes. In practice, you may want to check if you didn't include some webapp-required libraries in the classpath of Tomcat 5.5. You may want to copy them to Tomcat 6.0 or to just include them in your webapp. Further there may be webapp-required configuration settings somewhere in `/conf` folder, such as JNDI datasources. You may want to copy those settings to Tomcat 6.0 or to put it in webapp's own `META-INF/context.xml`.